# Understanding Instruments and the All Heap & Anonymous VM

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, xcode7, instruments, allocation

I am trying to understand the "All Heap & Anonymous VM" inside Instruments / Allocation.

This is the thing: I just create a new Swift SpriteKit project and without doing anything I got the next results:

[image]

As you can see, the heaps are growing up. Nevertheless I don't have memory Leaks. How can I explain that? Is this a good result?

Comment: its ok there is no problem untill your device not throwing a memory warning again and again there are serval system libs you are using so there are many malloc() or calloc() calls. secondly under arc you don't have to worry about heap and Allocation. arc automatically release memory when you move from one SKScene to another or one view to another (until you don't have any strong reference)  SKScene and All Heap & Anonymous VM would automatically reduce down.

Answer (score 3):

Focus on the Live Bytes column for All Heap Allocations to see how much memory your application is using. You cannot control your application's Anonymous VM size.

> Focus on the heap allocations because your app has more control over
> heap allocations. **Most of the memory allocations your app makes are
> heap allocations.**
>
> The VM in anonymous VM stands for virtual memory.
> When your app launches, the operating system reserves a block of
> virtual memory for your application. This block is usually much larger
> than the amount of memory your app needs. When your app allocates
> memory, the operating system allocates the memory from the block it
> reserved.
>
> Remember the second sentence in the previous paragraph. The operating
> system determines the size of the virtual memory block, not your app.
> That’s why you should focus on the heap allocations instead of
> anonymous VM. **Your app has no control over the size of the anonymous
> VM.**

Source: http://meandmark.com/blog/2014/01/instruments-heap-allocations-and-anonymous-vm/

Comment: `Your app has no control over the size of the anonymous VM`. Not really, If you use any Graphics API like `OpenGL`, `Metal`, you may have control over like how many `vertexbuffer` the driver should allocate.

Comment: I think Anonymous VM is memory allocated by the app but not through malloc(), so not in the heap. When the app asks for memory pages to the kernel, for instance, this is not managed by the heap and appear as "anonymous". Some frameworks have their own memory management (their own heap) and do not use the main heap. In Instrument you can see exactly how many allocations are anonymous and where in the source code the allocation took place. The answer above seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Information of Allocation doesn't include using of  VRAM(Video Memory), so it doesn't show a completed status of APP memory, which Xcode memory report did.

If you are using graphics rendering API, memory will increasing much faster than you thought. Size of OpenGL/Metal objects are created by graphics API in VRAM would count as APP memory using.

Many OpenGL instruction would copy data from RAM to VRAM for GPU consumption.

For example, if you create many texture and set image data to it. the heap allocation is much fewer than VARM allocation.

[image: 内存增长曲线]

[image: Allocation]

Remind `MemoryWarning` will receive when using too much gross of RAM and VRAM.